# On updating, it shows System.ListException: Duplicate id in list: 0015j00000eFggSAAS

Tags: exception, duplicate-management

I am having this exception on after update trigger on updating any MailingState field of contact object. I want to update the value of Contact's 'MailingState' field to the Account's 'BillingState' field. I built a map to store the accountId and List of MailingState (Contact field).  I have got the result using different approach but I wanna why it is showing this error and how to fix it...

```
    Map<Id, Set<String>> mapOfAccIdBillinStateList = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();  // to store AccId and MailingStateList
        List<Contact> retConList01 = [SELECT ID, AccountId, MailingState FROM Contact];
        if(retConList01!=null && retConList01.size()>0) {
            for (Contact conObj : retConList01) {
                if(!mapOfAccIdBillinStateList.containsKey(conObj.AccountId)) {
                    mapOfAccIdBillinStateList.put(conObj.AccountId, new Set<String>());
                }
                mapOfAccIdBillinStateList.get(conObj.AccountId).add(conObj.MailingState);
            }
        }
List<Account> newAccList01 = new List<Account>();
        if (mapOfAccIdBillinStateList!=null && mapOfAccIdBillinStateList.size()>0) {
            for (Id key : mapOfAccIdBillinStateList.keySet()) {
                for (String value : mapOfAccIdBillinStateList.get(key)) {
                    newAccList01.add(new Account(Id = key, BillingState = value));
                }
            }
        }
        update newAccList01;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're adding the same account to the list for each billing state on the contact. So, if there's more than two billing states, you're going to end up with duplicates in the list, which is not allowed. To fix it, you'd have to use just one value. You could have written it something like:

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
for(Contact conObj: retConList01) {
  accounts.put(conObj.AccountId, new Account(Id=conObj.AccountId, BillingState=conObj.MailingState));
}
update accounts.values();
```

Note that you can only store one value, so the rest would be overridden. How you determine which value to use depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by using **Automation Tools** Workflow/Process Builder/Flow.

Coming to the code:

```
if (mapOfAccIdBillinStateList != null && mapOfAccIdBillinStateList.size() > 0) {
  for (Id key: mapOfAccIdBillinStateList.keySet()) {
    for (String value: mapOfAccIdBillinStateList.get(key)) {
       newAccList01.add(new Account(Id = key, BillingState = value));
    }
  }
}
```

Example: There are two contacts updated.

```
contact1 -> AccountId1 , IN
Contact2 -> AccountId1 , AP
```

then As per the code

---

> newAccList01.add(new Account(Id = key, BillingState = value));

---

it will add two Accounts with the same Id

```
[
    Account{Id=AccountId1 ,BillingState =IN},
    Account{Id=AccountId1 ,BillingState =AP}
]
```

Means *List has more than one Account with the same Account Id*

**Solution:**  Use **Set or Map** instead of *List*

Or Check List has the same Account or not.